# Getting No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? error while running code using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline

Getting No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? error while running code using azure devops I am using the below pom.xml, it's running perfectly fine on my local machine.
i am using below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project : Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment.
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914737/15969115 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467737

Comment: You can refer to [Eclipse/Maven error: "No compiler is provided in this environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099072/eclipse-maven-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment) , [No compiler is provided in this environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738528/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-although-i-can-build-other-project) and [Maven build Compilation error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525139/maven-build-compilation-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugins)